# Simplify expression $-\ln(2)2x\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{x^2+1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I can't seem to see the how the expression was simplified from

$$-\ln(2)2x\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{x^2+1}$$

to

$$-\ln(2)x\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{x^2}$$
I am sure I am missing something, and it is probably a simple solution.

Please help.

Comment: It is not an "equation" because there is no sign "equal" in it. It is an "expression"

Comment: @JeanMarie Fixed it :)

Answer (score 1):

Remember that

$$\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{x^2+1}=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{x^2}\frac{1}{2}.$$

Here are some rules for handling exponents that would be good to learn by heart:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

$$-\left(\frac 12\right)^{x^2+1}\ln 2\cdot 2x=-2x\frac{1}{2^{x^2+1}}\ln 2=-\frac{x\ln 2}{2^{x^2}}=-x\ln 2 \left(\frac 12\right)^{x^2}$$